# Ruby: Are comments tokens?

Tags: ruby

I've just read here (http://ruby.runpaint.org/programs#lexical) that comments are tokens. I've never thought of comments as tokens as they're either annotations or for a post-processor.

Are comments really tokens or is this source wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah they're tokens to the parser. Usually, if you use a parser generator this is the definition of a comment

```
{code} short_comment = '//' not_cr_lf* eol | '#' not_cr_lf* eol;
{code} long_comment = '/*' not_star* '*'+ (not_star_slash not_star* '*'+)* '/';  /* '4vim */
Ignored Tokens
  short_comment,
  long_comment;
```

This is a SableCC grammar. They're usually ignored tokens.

Remember that everything you write in a source code is a token, that's always the first step. The parser needs to start building the abstract syntax tree from tokens.

Comment: Thank you. Is white space a token too then? I was under the impression that white space wasn't a token, but just influenced the recognition of other tokens.

Comment: White space is usually ignored by the scanner (the program generating the token stream). There are of course languages where white spaces are significant such as Python and CoffeeScript.

Comment: Matty: that depends on the language. As Christoph said, some languages use significant whitespace. In that case you usually keep track of the current indentation level and e.g. add a new scope on top when the level increases/pop off one scope when the level decreases.

Comment: I just had a look at the draft Ruby specification, and in this case it appears white space isn't considered a token, but usually just as a separator tokens.

Comment: It depends on how you write your parser. Actually you can be more specific. e.g. in Python the important ones are \t and \s are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they should be tokens, but ignored by the parser later on. If you do `ruby --dump parsetree foo.rb` with a file that looks like this

```
# this is a comment
1+1
# another comment
```

this is what you'll get:

```
# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 3)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_CALL (line: 2)
#     +- nd_mid: :+
#     +- nd_recv:
#     |   @ NODE_LIT (line: 2)
#     |   +- nd_lit: 1
#     +- nd_args:
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 2)
#         +- nd_alen: 1
#         +- nd_head:
#         |   @ NODE_LIT (line: 2)
#         |   +- nd_lit: 1
#         +- nd_next:
#             (null node)
```